# Fill the area between two curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

Hi I am trying to fill the area between two curves. One curve is two joined arcs, and the other is one freehand curve. The part I want to fill is the white area. I use the `fillbetween` library but I just can't get the upper curve right.
[image]
[image]

Your help is much appreciated. A MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[x=1cm, y=1cm]
\def\rsmall{2}
\def\rlarge{4}
\def\alpha{60}
\def\beta{40}
\def\gamma{20}
\def\Aout{\alpha+\gamma-90}
\def\Bin{270-\beta-\gamma}

\pgfmathsetmacro\ax{-\rsmall+cos(\alpha)*\rsmall}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ay{sin(\alpha)*\rsmall}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bx{\rlarge-cos(\beta)*\rlarge}
\pgfmathsetmacro\by{sin(\beta)*\rlarge}

\filldraw[name path=arcs, fill=gray!20, thick]
    (180:2*\rsmall) arc (180:0:\rsmall) arc (180:0:\rlarge);

\coordinate (A) at (\ax, \ay);
\coordinate (B) at (\bx, \by);

\draw[name path=unduloid, thick] (A) to[out=\Aout, in=\Bin] (B);


\fill[blue!20,intersection segments={of=unduloid and arcs,sequence={L2--R2}}];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You only need to add a `[reverse]` to one of the segments.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[x=1cm, y=1cm]
\def\rsmall{2}
\def\rlarge{4}
\def\alpha{60}
\def\beta{40}
\def\gamma{20}
\def\Aout{\alpha+\gamma-90}
\def\Bin{270-\beta-\gamma}

\pgfmathsetmacro\ax{-\rsmall+cos(\alpha)*\rsmall}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ay{sin(\alpha)*\rsmall}
\pgfmathsetmacro\bx{\rlarge-cos(\beta)*\rlarge}
\pgfmathsetmacro\by{sin(\beta)*\rlarge}

\filldraw[name path=arcs, fill=gray!20, thick]
    (180:2*\rsmall) arc (180:0:\rsmall) arc (180:0:\rlarge);

\coordinate (A) at (\ax, \ay);
\coordinate (B) at (\bx, \by);

\draw[name path=unduloid, thick] (A) to[out=\Aout, in=\Bin] (B);


\path[%draw=red,thick,
fill=blue!20,intersection segments={of=unduloid and arcs,sequence={L2--R2[reverse]}}];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can one debug this? Just draw curves with arrows on the segments in question. Here one would add

```
\draw[red,thick,-latex,
intersection segments={of=unduloid and arcs,sequence={L2}}];

\draw[blue,thick,-latex,
intersection segments={of=unduloid and arcs,sequence={R2}}];
```

and then get

[image]

This means that the paths start and end at the same points. To fix this, i.e. to produce a cycle, you have to run through one of the paths in the `reverse` direction. If you don't, Ti*k*Z will close the path on its own by a straight line. That's why you got the straight line for one of the bounding curves.

**ADDENDUM**: In this situation you do not really need all the segments nor the `fillbetween` library. Personally I would also refrain from redefining `\alpha`, `\beta` etc. since you may need these Greek symbols.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[x=1cm, y=1cm]
\def\rsmall{2}
\def\rlarge{4}
\def\myalpha{60}
\def\mybeta{40}
\def\gamma{20}
\def\Aout{\myalpha+\gamma-90}
\def\Bin{270-\mybeta-\gamma}


\filldraw[fill=gray!20, thick]
    (180:2*\rsmall) arc (180:0:\rsmall) arc (180:0:\rlarge);

\coordinate (A) at ($(-\rsmall,0)+(\myalpha:\rsmall)$);
\coordinate (B) at ($(\rlarge,0)+(180-\mybeta:\rlarge)$);

\draw[red,fill=blue!20, thick] (A) to[out=\Aout, in=\Bin] (B)
arc(180-\mybeta:180:\rlarge) arc(0:\myalpha:\rsmall) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]