# Shading under the curve problem

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
            mark=between positions #1 and 1 step #1 with {\arrow{>}}}},
    arrow marks/.default=10pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.7in}{-0.7in}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            [declare function={a=0.5;lambda=5;}]

            \begin{axis}[
            %xtick distance = {1},
            %ytick distance = {1},
            xmin=-12,xmax=12,
            ymin=-8,ymax=8,
            height = 7in,width=1.2\textwidth,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
            %axis equal,
            legend cell align = {left},
            every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,}, 
            title= {Bang-off-bang Control Trajectories},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=2em},
            domain=-15:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
            %Final Switch Curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = blue, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.3, font = \small] {\(u^* = 1\)};


            %Final Switch Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = red, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.3, font = \small] {\(u^* = -1\)};

            %Off Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+(lambda*a*x)/(lambda + 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};

            %Off curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-(lambda*a*x)/(lambda - 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};


            \addplot[name path =FinSwCurveX2Neg,draw=none,domain = -8:0]({-ln(1-a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \addplot[name path =FinSwCurveX2Pos,draw=none, domain = 8:0]({ln(1+a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \addplot[name path=ZeroSwCurveX2Pos,dotted, color = black, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+(lambda*a*x)/(lambda + 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \addplot[name path = ZeroSwCurveX2Neg,dotted, color = black, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-(lambda*a*x)/(lambda - 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \addplot[color = orange,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= FinSwCurveX2Neg and ZeroSwCurveX2Neg];
            \addplot[color = orange,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= FinSwCurveX2Pos and ZeroSwCurveX2Pos];

            \addplot[name path = xAxisNeg, draw = none, domain = -12:0]{0};
            \addplot[name path = xAxisPos, draw = none, domain = 0:12]{0};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisNeg1, draw = none] coordinates{(0, -8) (0, 0)};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisNeg2, draw = none] coordinates{(-12, -8) (-12, 0)};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisPos1, draw = none] coordinates{(0, 0) (0, 8)};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisPos2, draw = none] coordinates{(12, 0) (12, 8)};
            \addplot[name path= yMax,thick, draw = none, domain=ln(1+(lambda*a*8)/(lambda + 2*a*8))/a^2 - 8/a:0] {8};
            \addplot[name path= yMin,thick, draw = none, domain= 0:-ln(1-(lambda*a*8)/(lambda - 2*a*8))/a^2 - 8/a] {-8};
            %yMax and yMin are used so that the second quadrant above s1 and the fourth quadrant below s2 are respectively properly colored
            \addplot[color = blue,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= ZeroSwCurveX2Pos and xAxisNeg];
            \addplot[color = blue,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= yAxisNeg1 and yAxisNeg2]; %colors the third quadrant
            \addplot[color = blue, fill opacity = 0.2] fill between[
            of = yMin and FinSwCurveX2Neg]; %For some reason, the blue color doesn't clip off at the y-axis, but rather goes past it
            \addplot[color = red,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= ZeroSwCurveX2Neg and xAxisPos]; %colors entire third quadrant blue
            \addplot[color = red,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= yAxisPos1 and yAxisPos2]; %colors entire first quadrant red
            \addplot[color = red,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= yMax and FinSwCurveX2Pos];
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustwidth} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

What I am trying to do is that area shaded underneath the solid blue curve on the fourth quadrant. However, that shaded area overflows to the third quadrant. I think that the area is shaded from top to bottom. What could be the problem, and how to fix it? Also, is there a way to use the `fillbetween` command between *three* paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to restrict yourself to the `fill between` possibility. An arguably more powerful option is to fill between intersection segments. I added a path for the negative y axis and fill

```
\path [name path=BC,%draw=cyan,thick,->,
            fill = blue, fill opacity = 0.2,
            intersection segments={of=FinSwCurveX2Neg and negative y axis,
            sequence={A0 -- B1}, },] -- cycle;
```

which yields

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
            mark=between positions #1 and 1 step #1 with {\arrow{>}}}},
    arrow marks/.default=10pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.7in}{-0.7in}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            [declare function={a=0.5;lambda=5;}]

            \begin{axis}[
            %xtick distance = {1},
            %ytick distance = {1},
            xmin=-12,xmax=12,
            ymin=-8,ymax=8,
            height = 7in,width=1.2\textwidth,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
            %axis equal,
            legend cell align = {left},
            every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,}, 
            title= {Bang-off-bang Control Trajectories},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=2em},
            domain=-15:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
            %Final Switch Curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = blue, thick, domain =
                -8:0,tips=proper,name path=blue]({-ln(1-a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.3, font
                = \small] {\(u^* = 1\)};


            %Final Switch Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = red, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.3, font = \small] {\(u^* = -1\)};

            %Off Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+(lambda*a*x)/(lambda + 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};

            %Off curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-(lambda*a*x)/(lambda - 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};


            \addplot[name path =FinSwCurveX2Neg,draw=none,domain =
            -8:0,draw=none]({-ln(1-a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \path[name path=negative y axis] (0,0) -- (0,-8);
            \addplot[name path =FinSwCurveX2Pos,draw=none, domain = 8:0]({ln(1+a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \addplot[name path=ZeroSwCurveX2Pos,dotted, color = black, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+(lambda*a*x)/(lambda + 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \addplot[name path = ZeroSwCurveX2Neg,dotted, color = black, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-(lambda*a*x)/(lambda - 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x});
            \addplot[color = orange,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= FinSwCurveX2Neg and ZeroSwCurveX2Neg];
            \addplot[color = orange,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= FinSwCurveX2Pos and ZeroSwCurveX2Pos];

            \addplot[name path = xAxisNeg, draw = none, domain = -12:0]{0};
            \addplot[name path = xAxisPos, draw = none, domain = 0:12]{0};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisNeg1, draw = none] coordinates{(0, -8) (0, 0)};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisNeg2, draw = none] coordinates{(-12, -8) (-12, 0)};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisPos1, draw = none] coordinates{(0, 0) (0, 8)};
            \addplot[name path = yAxisPos2, draw = none] coordinates{(12, 0) (12, 8)};
            \addplot[name path= yMax,thick, draw = none, domain=ln(1+(lambda*a*8)/(lambda + 2*a*8))/a^2 - 8/a:0] {8};
            \addplot[name path= yMin,thick, draw = none, domain= 0:-ln(1-(lambda*a*8)/(lambda - 2*a*8))/a^2 - 8/a] {-8};
            %yMax and yMin are used so that the second quadrant above s1 and the fourth quadrant below s2 are respectively properly colored
            \addplot[color = blue,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= ZeroSwCurveX2Pos and xAxisNeg];
            \addplot[color = blue,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= yAxisNeg1 and yAxisNeg2]; %colors the third quadrant
%             \addplot[color = blue, fill opacity = 0.2] fill between[
%             of = yMin and FinSwCurveX2Neg]; %For some reason, the blue color doesn't clip off at the y-axis, but rather goes past it
            %
            \path [name path=BC,%draw=cyan,thick,->,
                fill = blue, fill opacity = 0.2,
                intersection segments={of=FinSwCurveX2Neg and negative y axis,
                sequence={A0 -- B1}, },] -- cycle;
            %
            \addplot[color = red,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= ZeroSwCurveX2Neg and xAxisPos]; %colors entire third quadrant blue
            \addplot[color = red,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= yAxisPos1 and yAxisPos2]; %colors entire first quadrant red
            \addplot[color = red,fill opacity=0.2]fill between[of= yMax and FinSwCurveX2Pos];
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustwidth} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar comments apply to your other shaded regions but there you seem to get what you want.

Comment: Cool! In fact, I found an ad hoc way which is to color the third quadrant white then recolor it with axis on top option. I feel that your method is more direct and concise. I was looking for a direct and concise solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: I looked more into the code, what does `sequence={A0 -- B1}` do? I have seen on this link (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417970/filling-area-between-two-bezier-curves-with-tikz), that there are different versions like `sequence={A1[reverse] -- B1}`and `sequence={A1 -- B1}`. How to the numbers affect the result, and what does A and B mean? Finally, what does `reverse` do?

Comment: @Superman The intersecting paths get decomposed into intersection segments, which are labeled `A0`, `A1` ... for the first path and `B0`, `B1`, ... for the second. `[reverse]` means that the corresponding segment is to be reversed, which is important for fills. So `sequence={A1[reverse] -- B1}` means "run through the second segment of the first path in the opposite direction and then through the second segment of the second path in the original direction of that path".

Comment: Hmmmm, I may need a visual on how this works. Should I make another query following up on this? Sorry for the repeated questions, I want to make sure that I fully understand the code before I use it.

Comment: In this scenario, `A` represents `FinSwCurveX2Neg`, while `B` represents `negative y axis`. Then, `A0` represents "first segment of A" and `B1` represents "second segment of B." When to use which numbers for the *k*th segment?

Comment: @Superman Maybe [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447266/194703) has all the explanations you need.

Comment: I looked more into [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458536/drawing-path-from-intersection-of-two-paths-to-origin-of-those-two-intersecting), here its uses `L` and `R` for the first and second segment, respectively, instead of `A` and `B`. Also, it's newer, according to user121799. Would that be valid for this code as well?

Comment: Also, I found [this manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) p. 448. It uses `L` and `R`.

Comment: @Superman Yes, in the manual they use `A` and `B`. I believe to remember that `L` and `R` may have a small disadvantage, but I am not sure if my recollection is accurate.

Comment: Hmmm the manual says this on p. 448: "Note that there is actually another syntax: you can use A(0-based-index) for the first input path and B(0-based-index) for the second input path. These identifiers were introduced in pgfplots 1.10, but have been deprecated in favor of 1-based indices. The old syntax with 0-based indices will still remain available. It is advised to use L and R instead of A and B." I wonder if A and B are deprecated due to user preference.

Comment: @Superman OK, good, I always confuse them. This raises the question why the examples in the manual use `A` and `B` on pages 443, 444, say.

Comment: By the way, is there a way to incorporate *three* paths instead of two (E.g. `FinSwCurveX2Pos - - ZeroSwCurveX2Neg  |- cycle` to color it red)?

Comment: @Superman Yes, you need to build up the paths in steps, see e.g. the second code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541478/194703).

Comment: Oh, it looks like one can only do two *different* paths at a time instead of three. I was looking if one can do more than 2 paths in one go instead of in steps.

Comment: @Superman This is not supported AFAIK. You have to build up the path.

Comment: Oh well. Anyways, thank you so much for your help!